# vTiger 7 Custom Entity Module Not displaying data

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am using vTiger 7 and creating a custom Entity Module using vtlib/tools/console.php but somehow when i save the data it shows me error **"Record You are trying to access is not found"** although it saves the data in tables but when i try to show the data it shows the same error.

Comment: could you provide the code you are using?

Comment: i am creating the module using vtlib/tools/console.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue and I solved the problem by creating a table manually.

See the schema of table `vtiger_leads_user_field` to create new table having same schema.

Create **new table** as `vtiger_<your entity module name>_user_field`. In vtiger 7, when you create new module the `vtiger_......._user_field` table is not being created.

Some other problem also with vTiger 7 but I think this problem i solved by just creating a table in DB, which must be created automatically by vtiger 7.

**NOTE:** I created my module using custom PHP script (Module Creator).

Comment: That was super awesome. Thanks!

Comment: How can i add this custom module in the sidebar?

Comment: post new question containing module name and where you wanna put that module and what you want actually.

Comment: Right. i've posted a new question

Comment: @AeyzazKhan see the answer